# moment.js and moment-timezone-with-data.js gives arror Unknown Provider - Moment Provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to use **moment.js** and **moment-timezone-with-data.js** in my application to display the dates in any timezone.

I have included the cdn for both of these js files in my **index.html** and added moment as required in my controller.

It gives -

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=momentProvider%20%3C-%20moment%20%3C-%20manageScheduleController

My Code:

index.html - cdn for both these js files.

Controller:

```
.controller('manageScheduleController', function($http,$scope,sessiontracker, 
     $window,$filter, $dialogs, Upload, $timeout,moment)
```

Comment: Where are you injecting these into the controller? Should be: controller('manageScheduleController', ['$http', '$scope', 'sessiontracker', '$window', '$filter', '$dialogs', 'Upload', '$timeout', 'moment', function($http, $scope, sessiontracker, $window, $filter, $dialogs, Upload, $timeout, moment) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`moment-timezone-with-data`** is Javascript library on the top of momentjs. You can directly use it inside angular application by just using `moment` variable. (You could consider creating wrapper `constant` for the same so that you can mock at the time of testing the same).

There you don't need to inject `moment` inside controller factory function as dependency. Removing `moment` parameter from controller function will fix the problem.

> **Note:** Make sure you had reference `moment-timezone-with-data.js` on your `index.html` page.